# How to reset the stats displayed in the statistics tracker?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play on my own server and I want to reset the stats. I'm talking about the stats you get when you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then click on 'Statistics'.

You can see this in some big servers, for example on hypixel, when you log out then back in, the "games quit" stat shows as zero.

How do people do that?

Answer (score 1):

From the wiki:

> Statistics are stored in […] `world name/stats/`*`<uuid>`*`.json` on servers.
> <sub>https://minecraft.wiki/w/Statistics#Storage ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Statistics&oldid=1548320#Storage))</sub>

`<uuid>` here stands for the UUID of the player, which can be retrieved for example with `/data get entity <player_name>`. Deleting the file will reset the statistics for that player. Deleting the entire folder deletes all statistics.

(Warning, not tested: Deleting the contents of that folder and then removing write access to it might make statistics never save. But it might also simply crash the game.)